# Extracting azure AD users by createdDateTime using graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to extract users created for last 6 months for the first time and for the subsequent runs its going to be delta.  I used Microsoft Graph API for extracting user by using using createdDateTime filter.But Its throwing an error.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=CreatedDateTime ge '2019-04-26T21:15:12Z'.

Is there a way of extracting users based on last modified date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering objects by date in MS Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54182538/filtering-objects-by-date-in-ms-graph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have confirmed with Azure support engineer that filter is not supported on the createdDateTime property for the API groups.

The workaround is to fetch the full user collection and filter out locally.

Comment: When I get a list of users from the graph API locally, it does not include the property "CreatedDateTime" or any other created timestamp. Am I missing something?