# Filtering Azure AD Sign in logs using "createdDateTime" property not working

Tags: azure-active-directory

when i try to hit the below endpoint I get response exactly the way I wanted but the same when I try to fetch Azure AD Sign in logs using filter "createdDateTime" isn't working.

The below one is working
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=createdDateTime ge  2020-06-19T08:00:00Z

This one is not working at the moment.
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=createdDateTime ge  2020-06-19T08:00:00Z

According to the below post, usage of "createdDateTime" property isn't supported. i was wondering by any chance this option is available by now.
Ref: [Extracting azure AD users by createdDateTime using graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58542571/extracting-azure-ad-users-by-createddatetime-using-graph-api)

please assist if possible.

Comment: If it helps you, please accept it as answer. Click the checkmark to turn it green.

Answer (score 0):

> According to the below post, usage of "createdDateTime" property isn't supported. i was wondering by any chance this option is available by now.

For now, [user resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta) is support filter `createdDateTime` property.

[image]

For [listing azure ad sign in logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), you need to assign user some permission.

[image]

The working output is as below:

[image]

Comment: I have all the required permissions to hit the endpoint. Actually the problem is that its not printing the expected logs which are greater than 2020-June-19. when you test it, try scrolling it down to the bottom to see if it gives all the log entries as expected.

Comment: Microsoft Graph returns an `@odata.nextLink` property in the response that contains the URL to the next page of results.

Comment: Because the data is too large, you could use `@data.nextLink` to get multiple pages of data. Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

As you can see that I have all the required permissions to hit the endpoint. the actually problem that I am facing is that its not printing the expected logs which are greater than 2020-June-19(its not older than 30 days from now-fyi). if you scroll down to the bottom it only shows up today's logs but not the old data. this is the problem I am facing from the beginning. please see the screenshot below for your reference

please correct me if I need to correct something in the way I am requesting the end point.

[CreateDataTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diFMR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

As you can see that I have all the required permissions to hit the endpoint. the actually problem that I am facing is that its not printing the expected logs which are greater than 2020-June-19(its not older than 30 days from now-fyi). if you scroll down to the bottom it only shows up today's logs but not the old data. this is the problem I am facing from the beginning. please see the screenshot below for your reference

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j3R2.png)

please correct me if I need to correct something in the way I am requesting the end point.