# Graph API: Schema Extension Date filter not working

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using a Schema Extension for [Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-schema-groups). Filtering is not working for date values of this extension.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=ext123455_UserExtension&$filter=ext123455_UserExtension/CreationDate ge '2020-02-08T09:59:20.8368277Z'
```

The response contains results where date CreationDate property is lower than 2020:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(ext123455_UserExtension)",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "23d17258-515c-4685-b95e-f98f2df8df56",
            "ext123455_UserExtension": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.ComplexExtensionValue",
                "CreationDate": "2019-02-08T09:59:20.8354838Z",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The extension schema is:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#schemaExtensions/$entity",
    "id": "ext123455_UserExtension",
    "description": "Extension Test",
    "targetTypes": [
        "user"
    ],
    "status": "InDevelopment",
    "owner": "...",
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "CreationDate",
            "type": "DateTime"
        }
    ]
}
```

This could be connected to this question:
[Filtering objects by date in MS Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54182538/filtering-objects-by-date-in-ms-graph)

P.S. This post has somehow disappeared from stackoverflow. I have therefore recreated it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this won't work as AAD resources do not support `ge`.
From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter):

> Note: The following `$filter` operators are not supported for Azure AD resources: `ne`, `gt`, `ge`, `lt`, `le`, and `not`. The contains string operator is currently not supported on any Microsoft Graph resources

Comment: Thanks. Would be better to put this note directly under the list of operators.